# Wordpress: How to assign different single.php templates to the same custom post type archive

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

First off, I'm a designer who's working my way through my own WordPress website builds, my knowledge is not advanced when it comes to WP dev. Here is what I would like to achieve...

1. I have a custom post type ‘events’ that's an archive
2. For the archive.php (archive-events.php) listings, my loop is using code (see below) to display only posts with my custom date field 'event-date' from today on
3. In a separate loop I am also using the same code in reverse to show post older than today to display past events which I want to keep for SEO, etc.
4. For each of the loops in my archive.php (archive-events.php) page I can assign a custom look using a different template, a layout for current events and a layout for past events like so

get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'current-event-listing' );
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'past-event-listing' );

**Now what I want to solve...**

5. Despite being able to use different template for the archive listings, all listing titles with permalinks use the same single.php (single-events.php) template
6. My goal is to modify the look of single.php (single-events.php) posts with past dates removing the signup form etc, but I can not figure out a way to this. Is it possible to assign different (single-events.php) for the same post type, so single-events.php and single--past-events.php

I appreciate any help!

```
<?php 
        
$time = current_time( 'timestamp' ); // Get current unix timestamp

// Set up custom query with meta_query to compare event start date with today's date
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events', // Tell WordPress which post type we want
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // We want to organize the events by date    
    'meta_key' => 'event_date', // Grab the "start date" field 
    'order' => 'ASC', // ASC is the other option    
    'posts_per_page' => '6', // Let's show only one / the first event.
    'meta_query' => array( // WordPress has all the results, now, return only the events after today's date
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date', // Check the start date field
            'value' => date("Y-m-d"), // Set today's date (note the similar format)
            'compare' => '>=', // Return the ones greater than or equal to today's date
            'type' => 'DATE' // Let WordPress know we're working with date
        )
    )
);?>
        <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) :?>


            <?php
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                $query->the_post(); // Start loop

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'event-listing' );

            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'no-events' );
            wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: Why not just add an if condition around the signup form that checks the event date?

Comment: @soulseekah that would work, but its beyond my knowledge, if you have some advice, or examples I’d greatly appreciate it. I would likely have a few instances as there are other pieces I’d like conditional such as pricing. Thank you.

Comment: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/php/